# SQL Server Insert in several Threads Deadlock

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, deadlock

I insert in one table with many concurrent threads, in this Table is a AFTER INSERT Trigger which updates one field on the inserted Row.
When this is executed in one thread everything is fine, but with many ones I got a Deadlock.
Is there something I can do?

Comment: Can you show us the SQL for the insert & trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either don't use multiple threads for this process - which I assume is not a reasonable option - or don't use the trigger, rather use a post-processing stored procedure to update all of the records at once.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you capture the Deadlock Event Graph in order to identify which database objects/resources are being contested for (and ultimately causing the Deadlocks).

See: [Detecting and Ending Deadlocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx)

You should also look at the execution plan/s for your queries involved in this process. You may find that a particular column is the source of contention(often via a Table/Index scan) which can be addressed through the deployment of a suitable index (in order to encourage an Index Seek operation).

Answer (score 0):

Could the Trigger be removed and the equivalent operation run by code, after all the updates have happened?
Or a Periodic procedure gets run to do the equivalent of the trigger?

Other than that I guess looking up on locking hints might be a good idea? Maybe your trigger could make use of the nolock hint?

Comment: NOLOCK doesnt help ... The statement looks like UPDATE field = 'some text' + otherfield WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED)

Comment: Did you try putting the locking hint on the select, as well as the update?
'UPDATE Table WITH NOLOCK set field = 'some text' + otherfield WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED WITH NOLOCK)' Or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

What if you update the value as part of the insert, rather than a post-insert trigger. You may also want to take a look at the db usage overall. there may be a way to reduce the chances of a deadlock by changing some of the queries.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in the long run is to avoid high concurrency altogether. Can you insert rows in bulk, via staging tables, or table-valued parameters? Can you do it from one connection? That could be mush faster and deadlock-free.

Although our system has a lot of OLTP modification, we have been completely deadlock-free since April at least.

[Also I wrote a canned answer with more approaches.](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/developing-modifications-that-survive-concurrency/)